# Primefaces sentinel fixed left menu position

Tags: css, primefaces, sentinel

I have a left menu position fixed problem in my primefaces panel application and I used sentinel theme. Left menu scrools with layout. If I add `style="position:fixed;"` layout sliding below the left menu. I want the left menu to have fixed height in my UI.

```
<div id="layout-menubar" class="Unselectable fontRegular" style=" height:100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="layout-menubarinner-box" id="buttonArea">
        <a href="#" id="layout-menubar-resize" class="BordRad3" title="Menu Resize"><i class="icon-th-list-2"></i></a>
        <a href="#" id="layout-menubar-resize2" class="BordRad3" title="Open Menu"><i class="icon-menu"></i></a>
    </div>

    <ps:menu id="sm_leftmenu_shop" rendered="#{loginBean.shopUser}">
        <p:menuitem id="sm_dashboard_entity" value="#{bundle.dashboardCamelCase}" icon="icon-home-outline" outcome="dashboard" containerStyleClass="layout-menubar-active"/>
        <p:menuitem id="sm_info_entity" value="#{bundle.info}" icon="icon-phone" outcome="contact" containerStyleClass="layout-menubar-active"/>
        <p:menuitem id="sm_campaigns_entity" value="#{bundle.campaigns}" icon="icon-megaphone" outcome="offers" containerStyleClass="layout-menubar-active"/>
        <p:menuitem id="sm_statistics_entity" value="#{bundle.Statistics}" icon="icon-chart-outline" outcome="statistics" containerStyleClass="layout-menubar-active"/>
    </ps:menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

create one file overrides.css

```
#layout-menubar {`position: fixed;`}

#layout-portlets-cover {`margin-left: 260px;`}
```

and add this file on template.xhtml